# Take JSON data from URL and display in HTML

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest

I need to create a html page which takes json data from a website and displays it.

Currently my code is this, which obviously doesn't do the job the way I wanted to but I wanted a starting point to display information from a page. Can anyone explain how I can go about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
(window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Click Button to display information!</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how you can do it:

This link will show you how to manipulate more in detail: http://jsfiddle.net/9zfHE/8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://example.com/",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("#myDiv").append("<tr id='bord'><td>"+i + "</td><td> " + field.name + "</td><td>" + field.description + "</td></tr>");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This link is exactly what you want as per it looks: http://jsfiddle.net/9zfHE/10/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://example.com/",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("#myDiv").append("<h4>" + field.name + "</h4><p>" + field.description + "</p>");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

You have to use ajax & .`getJSON` method which basically grabs fields from a url. Then I appended a table grabbing data from your json to the div.

If you add more data to your json then you can grab it by `field.[json-field-name]` and also give any style you like by providing 'id' to it & then styling in css. `i` keeps track of the number of elements in the json file.

Hope this helps

More documentation on: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

`Ajax` uses a jquery plugin which needs to be embedded in your page for the `.getJSON` method to work.

[EDIT:] This is how your html file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://example.com/",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("#myDiv").append("<h4>" + field.name + "</h4><p>" + field.description + "</p>");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Click Button to display information!</h2></div>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Change Content"></input>

<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whoa! Thanks a lot dude! 

I think I get it now :D

Comment: I edited the OP to what I think is how it should look using your example (Going to modify it myself later), sorry to bother you again but I'm still a little confused on how the end result should look.